# Maven import dependencies with classifier tag

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I try to import a dependency in POM in the following way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffe</artifactId>
    <version>master-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Because in local repository of this artifact, there are 4 jar files:
1) caffe-master-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar 2) caffe-master-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar 3) caffe-master-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar and 4) caffe-master-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT-linux-x86_64.jar, if I don't use "classifier" tag, only 1) 2) 3) will be imported. So to import all 4 jar files, I add this classifier.

The problem is, it still cannot import the 4) jar file into my project. But for other artifacts in the same project, I can import all 4 jar files in this way. Anyone would like help? Thanks.

Comment: "The problem is, it still cannot import the 4) jar file into my project. " Can you be more specific ?

Comment: As I understand, without classifier tag, 1) 2) 3) will be imported by default, but 4) will not be included. With this classifier, 4) will also be included into my project because this jar contains some C++ libraries I need to use. But the result is, with or without classifier tag, 4) is not included.

Comment: What's more, I also use classifier tag for other dependencies and it works exactly as I thought. That's why I am confused why it doesn't work only for this dependency.

Comment: I looks right. Sure you have no typo?

Comment: @JFMeierYes, I checked it and there should be no typo. Any possible reasons on this issue?

Comment: You've mentioned that these 4 jar files are in local repository. Could you please elaborate on how did they get there? Do you have same problem with release version 1.3?

Comment: I use "mvn install" to package these jars and put them there. The 4) jar file contains some native C++ libraries (.so library).

Comment: You've mentioned that you have no problem with other artifacts. Do you also "mvn install" them or do you get them from some public repository?

Comment: @VitalyZ I also use "mvn install" to put them there in local repository. So that's why I am confused why only this artifact cannot.